# Is it ok to get an external help for PHD dissertation?

Tags: phd, thesis

I study architecture. I came up with a research topic where I needed to create a tool to test it with a sample. I have all the necessary data, however, I need a programmer to code the tool for the sample to use. As I said, I have all the data that I can provide the programmer with. Is it ethical to seek such help or should I do it all myself?

Comment: I would think in architecture it's ok, as long as you attribute it ... you are doing architecture, not programming.  Of course, if you learn it yourself, it'd be a big plus for your career.  I'd ask your advisor, or some other trusted entity in your department, however.

Comment: Why couldn't this result in a publication with the programmer as a co-author?

Comment: @Anonymous wouldn't it be more suitable to mention them in acknowledgment? Co-authoring in architecture when you are a programmer seems off.

Comment: @Qise Judgment call, I guess, on how substantial the contribution is.  (And whether it's work for hire, I suppose.)  But if statistical analysis can warrant co-authorship, software contributions certainly can too.  At least in principle.

Comment: Are you doing computational design, building science, etc.. or History of architecture.  The field is very broad, and depends on your location and discipline. there are areas that would be more like data science, and you are asking someone to make a program to do the analysis for you.

Answer (score 5):

Before I retired, I was a statistical consultant and I often worked with people who were writing their dissertations. I always told my clients to make sure it was OK with their mentor and their committee. None reported having a problem.

I can't see why it would be a problem to hire a programmer for help in your situation; after all, a professional architect might do so. But it's always good to check.

Answer (score 3):

In general you can ask for help in research. For a dissertation, however, local rules may override the general one. Your advisor should provide the best guidance.

There shouldn't be any issues as long as you provide the intellectual content, not just the data, but the type of analysis that drives the programming. If the programming becomes a creative act, however, there could be a problem.

And you will need to give an acknowledgement of the help in the dissertation and any resulting publication.

If you have some programming experience, however, an alternative might be to provide the code and have someone more experienced check it. Or give you some initial guidance in structuring it. You probably need to avoid the situation where the contribution of another rises to the level of co-authorship, which is an issue for a dissertation. But your advisor can best guide you here.